# Where is the kernel source for Raspbian's default 3.1.9+ kernel?

Tags: raspbian, kernel

The default kernel version of Raspbian is 3.1.9+. When I try to compile an extra kernel module I have lots of error messages since the kernel header files are missing. I've checked the [Raspbian repository](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1179/does-raspbians-repository-have-a-browsable-package-list), but I was unable to find the 3.1.9+ kernel headers and kernel source.

If I search for 3.2.0 I can install the new kernel ( linux-image-3.2.0-3-rpi ), the headers ( linux-headers-3.2.0-3-rpi ), and the source ( linux-source-3.2 ) and I can compile the extra module. Unfortunately kernel 3.2 is very unstable for me, so this upgrade is not an option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to me, there is no kernel 3.1.9+ source deb package in Raspbian repository. [According to](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=11640&p=131656) Alex Bradbury (asb) they built the Raspbian kernel based on https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux. Based on [this](http://elinux.org/RPi_Performance) kernel compilation documentation I did the following (as root):

```
cd /usr/src
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux.git
ln -s linux linux-3.1.9+
cd linux
zcat /proc/config.gz > .config
ln -s /usr/src/linux /lib/modules/3.1.9+/build
```

After that I was able to recompile the external module.

*A few notes:*

- *I've cloned the latest version of the kernel source, which is newer than the Raspbian kernel image. If you really need the exact same kernel version then [this older version](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/commit/f6e4f04b715deaec1e48d475318e36e26efcee15) might be better.*
- *I've also recompiled the whole kernel just to be sure. Don't do that if you only need to compile an external module, since it takes hours.*
- *I had to modify the Makefile of the external module ( 8192cu ) a bit ( setting ARCH to arm instead of armv6l ).*

Comment: +1 Nice work. They should really get the headers into the repositories.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [rpi-source](https://github.com/notro/rpi-source/wiki) to automatically find and install kernel sources for your running kernel.

Also see [cross compiling from Linux](http://elinux.org/Raspberry_Pi_Kernel_Compilation#2._Cross_compiling_from_Linux), to avoid waiting for hours to compile your new kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Stange how that is so difficult...All I can find is this package in the sources list:

```
Package: linux-libc-dev
Source: linux
Version: 3.2.21-1+rpi1
Architecture: armhf
Maintainer: Debian Kernel Team <debian-kernel@lists.debian.org>
Installed-Size: 2790
Conflicts: linux-kernel-headers
Replaces: linux-kernel-headers
Provides: linux-kernel-headers
Multi-Arch: same
Priority: optional
Section: devel
Filename: pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_3.2.21-1+rpi1_armhf.deb
Size: 764146
SHA256: b75b35ccf8e7fbac582ad08af9579a23095f9dbbc9e7369430e43d584afc48fd
SHA1: e8c3bb2a30483c51ee39b525becd6e213ae9c2c7
MD5sum: 840e28237198aa137dfcdb558ef1cbf5
Description: Linux support headers for userspace development
 This package provides userspaces headers from the Linux kernel.  These
 headers are used by the installed headers for GNU glibc and other system
 libraries.
```

It seems to provide the tools you need, but I have no idea why there isn't a package called `linux-kernel-headers`.

However, if you look in the package archive you can find this:

http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/l/linux-latest/

Perhaps one of the headers packages in that directory will be for the kernel you need.

Unfortunately that is all the information I can currently offer, as I have not yet installed Raspbian myself, although it is on my TODO list.

Comment: On second thoughts, this is still the wrong version to the one you want isn't it?

Comment: This is also for kernel 3.2. The version number ( 3.2.21-1+rpi1 ) is the same for the packages I've mentioned in the question ( e.g. linux-headers-3.2.0-3-all_3.2.21-1+rpi1_armhf.deb )

Answer (score -1):

If you just need the kernel headers (for compiling modules, etc.), you can now also do this:

```
sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-kernel-headers
```

Source: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/headers.md