# What Version of Python does Raspbian Wheezy comes with?

Tags: raspbian, python

I would like to ask, What Version of Python does Raspbian Wheezy comes with?

Comment: use python -V command to get version of Python.

Answer (score 8):

It has Python 2.7 and 3.2 by default. Python 2.7 is the default to access Python 3.2 type python3 at the command line.

In future to answer this type of question (re: what version of a package is included or is a package available from the repository), you can search the distro's package list, or if you already have  your pi running, you can run the

```
apt-cache command
```

complete details for these methods can be found in this [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/1179/56)